# Pass SparseArray from one activity to other (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to parse SparseArray from one activity to other i tried many ways all not working

it's my last try
SparseArray sa;
after initialize and add data ....

```
    Intent intent=new Intent(Main.this,Other.class);
    intent.putExtra("sparsearray",(Serializable)sa);
    StartActivity();
```

this code do so strange thing it return when go to this line intent.putExtra("sparsearray",sa);
so if a toast under it toast never appear so strange really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your SparseArray in a Bundle and it should work.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSparseParcelableArray("SPARSE_ARRAY_KEY",sparseArray);
intent.putExtra("BUNDLE_KEY", bundle);
```

to get the SparseArray back you will need to unwrap the Bundle again.
Hope this helps.